# Connect to LocalDB of other system

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have connection string like this

```
_connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\310246067\Documents\Examcard.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

Now suppose I have same DB on another system can I directly connect it to using the connection string of that DB like

```
_connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(165.85.92.60)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\310246185\Desktop\WorkSpace\MiniProject\Examcard.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

I have created DB in VS like this

[image]

Comment: What is the question or problem? Do you mean "How to connect to localdb database on another PC" ?

Comment: I want to access data in other system without using SQL server management studio.  through VS, simply passing IP address

Comment: Can it be done without using SQL server management studio?

Comment: If you want to connect to another PC mdf-file using your LocalDB provider  for development purposes (e.g. add tables or generate dbml) then **yes**, but: 1) make mdf file available via network share (your local sql driver should be able to open it as file directly) 2) nobody else should work with that file (this is critical I think, as localDB is not designed to support not-local concurrency).

Comment: SSMS and VS connect to databases in exactly the same way. If you can do it with one, you can do it with the other, using the exact same settings. If you can't do it with SSMS, you can't do it with VS either